# How to insert auto increment value in temporary table in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, row, identity, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure where I am receiving a sequence number from the user interface. The stored procedure will select records from a table and insert them into a temporary table whose structure is same as the original table, except an additional column.

This column will hold the value "Sequence Number + 1". And for successive inserts, this value will auto increment. How should I do this? The column name where I want to keep the auto incremented value is "REV_SEQ"

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [PCC_APP_OWN].[Doc_GetBlChargePatternData] 
      @RevSeq INT NULL = 0,
      @TotalCount INT OUTPUT
  AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @DscgPort VARCHAR(7);
      DECLARE @tempRowId INT; 
      DECLARE @tempRevSeq INT; 

      SET @tempRevSeq = @RevSeq + 1;

      DECLARE @TempMenuResult AS TABLE (REV_SEQ INT,
                                        CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID INT,
                                        UPDT_STAMP DATETIME,
                                        UPDT_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                        ORGL_STAMP DATETIME,
                                        ORGL_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                        DEL_FLG VARCHAR(1),
                                        CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID INT,
                                        SEQ INT,
                                        CHRG_CODE VARCHAR(3),
                                        PORT_CODE VARCHAR(7),   
                                        BASIS VARCHAR(2),
                                        UM VARCHAR(2),
                                        RATE DECIMAL(8,2),
                                        CURRENCY VARCHAR(3),
                                        PER VARCHAR(2),
                                        PREPAID_COLLECT VARCHAR(1),
                                        INV_OFC VARCHAR(6)
                                       );   

    SELECT @DscgPort = DSCH_PORT 
    FROM BL 
    WHERE BL_NO_UID = 1 AND CA_SEQ = 0;

    INSERT INTO @TempMenuResult (REV_SEQ, CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID, UPDT_STAMP, UPDT_USER, ORGL_STAMP, ORGL_USER, DEL_FLG, CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID, SEQ, CHRG_CODE, PORT_CODE, BASIS, UM, RATE, CURRENCY, PER, PREPAID_COLLECT, INV_OFC)
        SELECT 
            IDENTITY(INT, @RevSeq, 1) AS id, * 
        FROM 
            CHRG_PTRN_DTL CHG_1 
        WHERE 
            CHG_1.CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID = @ChargePtrnHdrId 
            AND CHG_1.PORT_CODE = @DscgPort 
            AND CHG_1.DEL_FLG = 'N'

        UNION

        SELECT 
            IDENTITY(INT, @RevSeq, 1) AS id, * 
        FROM 
            CHRG_PTRN_DTL CHG_2 
        WHERE 
            CHG_2.PORT_CODE IS NULL 
            AND CHG_2.DEL_FLG = 'N';

    SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(1) OVER () FROM @TempMenuResult;
    SELECT * FROM @TempMenuResult ORDER BY REV_SEQ;
END
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: that SQL Server 2016

Comment: try, when you create column REV_SEQ INT Identity (RevSeq,1) and don't insert anything into it ... so it will start from your RevSeq number from parameter and continue increasing by 1 for every entry, of go with RevSeq + 1, 1 ... depends from which number you want it to start, after that remove insert into that column from other query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Identity seeds are not possible with Table Variables. Use Temp tables instead. Modify your table creation as below.

```
    DECLARE @sql varchar(8000);
    SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ##TempMenuResult; CREATE TABLE ##TempMenuResult (REV_SEQ INT IDENTITY('+ CAST(@tempRevSeq AS varchar(15)) + ', 1) NOT NULL ,
                                            CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID INT,
                                            UPDT_STAMP DATETIME,
                                            UPDT_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                            ORGL_STAMP DATETIME,
                                            ORGL_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                            DEL_FLG VARCHAR(1),
                                            CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID INT,
                                            SEQ INT,
                                            CHRG_CODE VARCHAR(3),
                                            PORT_CODE VARCHAR(7),   
                                            BASIS VARCHAR(2),
                                            UM VARCHAR(2),
                                            RATE DECIMAL(8,2),
                                            CURRENCY VARCHAR(3),
                                            PER VARCHAR(2),
                                            PREPAID_COLLECT VARCHAR(1),
                                            INV_OFC VARCHAR(6)
                                           );'
    EXEC (@sql);
    --Your code here to further process ##TempMenuResult
```

Edit: I don't have your DB but this could be modified SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PCC_APP_OWN].[Doc_GetBlChargePatternData] 
      @RevSeq INT NULL = 0,
      @TotalCount INT OUTPUT
  AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @DscgPort VARCHAR(7);
      DECLARE @tempRowId INT; 
      DECLARE @tempRevSeq INT; 

      SET @tempRevSeq = @RevSeq + 1;

      DECLARE @sql varchar(8000);
        SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ##TempMenuResult; CREATE TABLE ##TempMenuResult (REV_SEQ INT IDENTITY('+ CAST(@tempRevSeq AS varchar(15)) + ', 1) NOT NULL ,
                                            CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID INT,
                                            UPDT_STAMP DATETIME,
                                            UPDT_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                            ORGL_STAMP DATETIME,
                                            ORGL_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                            DEL_FLG VARCHAR(1),
                                            CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID INT,
                                            SEQ INT,
                                            CHRG_CODE VARCHAR(3),
                                            PORT_CODE VARCHAR(7),   
                                            BASIS VARCHAR(2),
                                            UM VARCHAR(2),
                                            RATE DECIMAL(8,2),
                                            CURRENCY VARCHAR(3),
                                            PER VARCHAR(2),
                                            PREPAID_COLLECT VARCHAR(1),
                                            INV_OFC VARCHAR(6)
                                           );'
    EXEC (@sql);

    SELECT @DscgPort = DSCH_PORT 
    FROM BL 
    WHERE BL_NO_UID = 1 AND CA_SEQ = 0;

    INSERT INTO #TempMenuResult (CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID, UPDT_STAMP, UPDT_USER, ORGL_STAMP, ORGL_USER, DEL_FLG, CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID, SEQ, CHRG_CODE, PORT_CODE, BASIS, UM, RATE, CURRENCY, PER, PREPAID_COLLECT, INV_OFC)
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            CHRG_PTRN_DTL CHG_1 
        WHERE 
            CHG_1.CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID = @ChargePtrnHdrId 
            AND CHG_1.PORT_CODE = @DscgPort 
            AND CHG_1.DEL_FLG = 'N'

        UNION

        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            CHRG_PTRN_DTL CHG_2 
        WHERE 
            CHG_2.PORT_CODE IS NULL 
            AND CHG_2.DEL_FLG = 'N';

    SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(1) OVER () FROM #TempMenuResult;
    SELECT * FROM #TempMenuResult ORDER BY REV_SEQ;
END
```

EDIT : If you don't want to use dynamic sql, Use DBCC CHECKIDENT to RESEED.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PCC_APP_OWN].[Doc_GetBlChargePatternData] 
      @RevSeq INT NULL = 0,
      @TotalCount INT OUTPUT
  AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @DscgPort VARCHAR(7);
      DECLARE @tempRowId INT; 
      DECLARE @tempRevSeq INT; 

      SET @tempRevSeq = @RevSeq + 1;


      DROP TABLE ##TempMenuResult; 
      CREATE TABLE ##TempMenuResult (REV_SEQ INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL ,
                                            CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID INT,
                                            UPDT_STAMP DATETIME,
                                            UPDT_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                            ORGL_STAMP DATETIME,
                                            ORGL_USER VARCHAR(12),
                                            DEL_FLG VARCHAR(1),
                                            CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID INT,
                                            SEQ INT,
                                            CHRG_CODE VARCHAR(3),
                                            PORT_CODE VARCHAR(7),   
                                            BASIS VARCHAR(2),
                                            UM VARCHAR(2),
                                            RATE DECIMAL(8,2),
                                            CURRENCY VARCHAR(3),
                                            PER VARCHAR(2),
                                            PREPAID_COLLECT VARCHAR(1),
                                            INV_OFC VARCHAR(6)
                                           );

    DBCC CHECKIDENT (##TempMenuResult, reseed, @tempRevSeq)

    SELECT @DscgPort = DSCH_PORT 
    FROM BL 
    WHERE BL_NO_UID = 1 AND CA_SEQ = 0;

    INSERT INTO #TempMenuResult (CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID, UPDT_STAMP, UPDT_USER, ORGL_STAMP, ORGL_USER, DEL_FLG, CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID, SEQ, CHRG_CODE, PORT_CODE, BASIS, UM, RATE, CURRENCY, PER, PREPAID_COLLECT, INV_OFC)
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            CHRG_PTRN_DTL CHG_1 
        WHERE 
            CHG_1.CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID = @ChargePtrnHdrId 
            AND CHG_1.PORT_CODE = @DscgPort 
            AND CHG_1.DEL_FLG = 'N'

        UNION

        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            CHRG_PTRN_DTL CHG_2 
        WHERE 
            CHG_2.PORT_CODE IS NULL 
            AND CHG_2.DEL_FLG = 'N';

    SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(1) OVER () FROM #TempMenuResult;
    SELECT * FROM #TempMenuResult ORDER BY REV_SEQ;
END
```

Comment: Must declare the table variable "@TempMenuResult". This is the error I am getting after implement your code.. The error is occurring on execution of the INSERT statement

Comment: Change @TempMenuResult to #TempMenuResult. in your further SP code.

Comment: It returns results successfully on first execution. But on next execution it gives error "There is already an object named '#TempMenuResult' in the database."

Comment: Missed it... edited to include DROP TABLE ##TempMenuResult; in the query

Comment: Can you tell me what would be the syntax for create temporary table if I dont use dynamic sql.  To be more precise, I need the syntax for identity column i.e. CREATE TABLE ##TempMenuResult (REV_SEQ INT IDENTITY('+ CAST(@tempRevSeq AS varchar(15)) + ', 1) NOT NULL        because the single quotes are not accepted

Comment: I have modified answer if you don;t want to use dynamic sql. You need to use DBCC Check Indent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134967/discussion-between-mit-and-arpita-dutta).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to do this by just declaring the column to be `identity`:

```
DECLARE @TempMenuResult AS TABLE (REV_SEQ INT IDENTITY, . . .);

. . .

INSERT INTO @TempMenuResult (CHRG_PTRN_DTL_ID, UPDT_STAMP, UPDT_USER, ORGL_STAMP, ORGL_USER, DEL_FLG, CHRG_PTRN_HDR_ID, SEQ, CHRG_CODE, PORT_CODE, BASIS, UM, RATE, CURRENCY, PER, PREPAID_COLLECT, INV_OFC)
    SELECT *
    . . .;
```

Then you have this statement:

```
SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(1) OVER () FROM @TempMenuResult;
```

Tis will probably not do what you want.  You want simple aggregation, not a window function:

```
SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(*) FROM @TempMenuResult;
```